# IntelliJ not picking up environment variables when using ZSH?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using oh-my-zsh for my terminal. I have set IntelliJ to use `/bin/zsh` as the shell path.  However no environment variable in my `.zshrc` file ever seems to get picked up.  I'm defining environment variables like this (for instance):

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$HOME/mailcreds.json"
```

But if I run:

```sh
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Nothing comes up.

Answer (score 11):

Set environment variables in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589) for details.

Comment: `~/.profile` is the login shell script you would use for bash, the zsh equivalent login file is `~/.zprofile`.  That said, "Workaround 3" from that Jetbrains link seems more palatable to me because the `/etc/zshrc` (for Mac) explicitly suggests overrides in .zshrc:
```zsh
$ cat /etc/zshrc | grep override
# Setup user specific overrides for this in ~/.zshrc. See zshbuiltins(1)
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, the issue was that I load `tmux` automatically using `.zshrc`.

I followed the solution here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-19/Shell-Environment-Loading

Wrapped just the `export ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true` like this:

```sh
if [ -z "$INTELLIJ_ENVIRONMENT_READER" ]; then
  export ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true
fi
```

Comment: this is exactly my case. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu, I edited my IDE desktop launcher to run zsh with [login interactive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/302105):

1. Go to `/usr/share/applications` (where the desktop entry usually located or `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` if you're using Snap).
2. Edit `jetbrains-idea.desktop`(might be named differently).
3. Change `Exec` field to include `/bin/zsh -l -i -c "/opt/intellij/bin/idea.sh"`.

The final result of the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
Icon=/opt/intellij/bin/idea.svg
Exec=/bin/zsh -l -i -c "/opt/intellij/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Capable and Ergonomic IDE for JVM
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
StartupNotify=true
```

Comment: For now this is the only solution working for my setup (I use zsh)

Answer (score 1):

Shared the same wrong behavior with *Intellij in Manjaro (Arch)*, which uses **zsh** by default.

The issue comes with **Flatpak**, switching to **Snap** or downloading binaries directly from vendor's page got this solved.

Is similar to this issue (PyCharm): https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate/issues/23.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by opening Intellij using the terminal.  You need to create Command Line Launcher if one doesn't exist.

1. Go to `Tools` -> `Create Command-line Launcher`
2. Then choose the location you prefer
3. Go to your terminal, and use that launcher command: `idea`

This will open Intellij and start your app, this should be able to access your system environment properties.